# JS: Get a substring of what's after number

Tags: javascript

Here's my problem:

I've got a string which is always made about the same:
3/4 letters - 3/4 digits - 2/3 letters

For exemple: "abc456mm" should return "mm", "ucw501mrf" should return "mrf", "ztui4001psl" -> "psl" etc.....

I need to get the two or three last characters, the ones after the number. I can't think of an easy way to achieve that because the length of the string can vary. Could someone help me, maybe with regexp ?

Thank you :)

Comment: please add to the example the wanted result and what you have tried already. some more use cases would be great as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can split the string on any number and then use the last element of that array

`var stringAfterNums = yourString.split(/[0-9]/).pop()`

Comment: Thanks ! This is the most understandable answer for me, and it is exactly how I do to find these characters as a human: I look what's after the numbers

Answer (score 0):

If you want the last characters, you can use `$` to match easily:

This regex should work:

```
/[a-z]+$/
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `match` and regex `/[A-Z]+$/gi` to get the alphabets at the end of input

```
"abc456mm".match(/[A-Z]+$/gi)
```

Or if the characters are not necessarily alphabets, then

```
"abc456mm".match(/[^\d]+$/gi)
```

Answer (score 0):

[Regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) can do this.

```
"abc456mm".replace(/^.*?([a-zA-Z]+)$/, '$1');
```

`([a-zA-Z]+)$` will match all characters at the end of the string.

```js
examples = ["abc456mm", "ucw501mrf"]
for (var i = 0; i < examples.length; i++)
{
    console.log(
        examples[i].replace(/^.*?([a-zA-Z]+)$/, '$1')
    );
}
```